LINQ fails to translate an SqlFunctions method
I have a problem with my C# app. I am trying to fetch an item from the SQL Server database, in the database I can use the following query:
SELECT *
FROM [table]
WHERE [field] IS NOT NULL 
    AND [field] != '' 
    AND CONCAT(REPLICATE('0', 10 - LEN([field])), [field]) = 'literal'

This works perfectly and returns the desired row on the table, so I KNOW for a fact that the item exists.
Then I try to access the same data from my C# backend I do so through a LINQ expression as follows:
var literal = 'xxxxx'
desired = dbContext.dbSet.Where(x => x.field != null && x.field != "" && (
    string.Concat(SqlFunctions.Replicate("0", 10 - x.CodigoProductoCia.Length), x.CodigoProductoCia) == literal
)

The previous snippet of code produces the following exception message:

The LINQ expression
DbSet<Entity>().Where(p => p.field != null && p.field != "" && SqlFunctions.Replicate(target: "0", count: (int?)(10 - p.CodigoProductoCia.Length)) + p.CodigoProductoCia == "") could not be translated.
Additional information: Translation of method 'System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlFunctions.Replicate' failed. If this method can be mapped to your custom function, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2132413 for more information. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.'

My understanding is that LINQ cannot translate the query to SQL, which is fair and all, but in honesty, I'm only using methods that work in LINQ, and string.Concat() produces the same result as simply a +.
In fact, the error is specifically complaining about SqlFunctions#Replicate which is a method SPECIFICALLY impossible to invoke outside of "LINQ to Entities" queries, which makes this even more confusing.
Any advice?

Are you using EF Core? If so, see Ef.Functions.

@JonasH But EF.Functions doesn't have REPLICATE

I would try avoid this replicate part. It makes the query non-sargable. Can't you strip leading zero's from literal before querying?

@GertArnold literal is actually being processed the same way as the field, but outside the query because LINQ was being pissy, I can't know if the leading 0s are necessary or not, so I need to basically make sure they both have max length and save whatever the input is, and process them every time to make sure they match. A limitation of handling many different formats of data together

SqlFunctions.Replicate is part of the System.Data and is not translated. EF Core analog is EF.Functions but currently it does not have an option for REPLICATE for SQL Server (see this github issue).
As workaround you can consider writing a user-defined function mapping  for now. For example:
class MyContext : DbContext
{  
    [DbFunction("REPLICATE", IsBuiltIn = true)]
    public static string Replicate(string s, int i) => throw new Exception();
    // ...
}

var firstOrDefault = myContext.Entities
    .Where(k => k.SomeId == 255080)
    .Select(k => new
    {
        k.SomeId,
        S = MyContext.Replicate(k.SomeString, 10 - k.SomeInt)
    })
    .FirstOrDefault();

See also:

Function Mappings of the Microsoft SQL Server Provider
SqlServerDbFunctionsExtensions:

Provides CLR methods that get translated to database functions when used in LINQ to Entities queries. The methods on this class are accessed via Functions.



